# systemctl status tomcat returns at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat

I have installed an Apache Httpd 2.4.6 and Tomcat 7.0.54 on RHEL 7.2 server with AJP connector and SSL configured and SELinux enabled.
When I start the Tomcat Server everything starts fine and the web application works fine too. However after a while if you run `# service tomcat status` or `systemctl status tomcat` , I get the following output.

```
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx logs]# service tomcat status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  tomcat.service
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-03-24 15:34:30 UTC; 1h 38min ago
  Process: 5929 ExecStop=/usr/libexec/tomcat/server stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5973 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
           └─5973 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx3072m -classpath /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar -Dcata...

Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
Mar 24 16:44:09 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-west-1.compute.internal server[5973]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't see any errors on Tomcat logs. Setting SELinux to permissive doesn't solve the issue.
How can I diagnose what the issue is and fix it?

Comment: The beginning of the stacktrace is more insteresting than the end.

Comment: My Apologies. I have amended the title now.

Comment: You should have something before `AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)`, the thrown exception.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, there's nothing before that. I have edited the question with the whole output now.

Comment: What about `journalctl -x -u tomcat` ?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. Turns out that it was a permission issue to a log file maintained by the application. I have fixed the ownership of the file and restarted Tomcat. All works fine with no errors now.

Comment: @rkosegi, How do I mark your comment as the answer? I can't seem to find that option.

Comment: @hos______ : I can post it as an answer, if it helps you.

Comment: @hos______ : Posted as answer

Comment: Of which while did you changes the ownership?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with `systemctl status tomcat` is that it will show only most recent log entries from service

Where `journalctl -x -u tomcat` will show log entries from last journal rotation.

More info about [systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) and [journalctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html)

Comment: Thanks very much! That helped in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Hi @Alfran. Sorry, this is over 4 years ago, so I don't remember specifics. Have you tried {journalctl -x -u tomcat} as suggested in the answer. That should give you the log entries from the previous log rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I fixed this problem using to file configuration try i first tomcat.service and if not work try another tomcat.service and vis versa

**First tomcat.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 9 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking


Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat9/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat9
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat9
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat9/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat9/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Second tomcat.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"
Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If the fist not work replace with the second and vis versa don't forgeo to use
sudo systemctl reload-daemon
sudo systemctl start tomcat
sudo systemctl enable tomcat
sudo systemctl status tomcat